# Is there a warning for floating point equality checking in visual studio (2013) c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, floating-point, warnings, compiler-warnings

I'm looking for a warning in MS visual studio 2013 similar to Gcc's -Wfloat-equal

I would like to turn on this warning, and compile my code, and find any places that i might need to re-examine for correctness.

I've looked through all the warnings here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ysb0wexw.aspx
and i haven't found it.